# Problem while integrating Zoom SDK in custom app

Tags: java, android, zoom-sdk

**Description**

I am trying to integrate Zoom SDK in my app. I was following steps provided by the documentation [here](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/android/getting-started/integration). I imported both the .arr modules i.e., in commonlibs and mobile rtc then I added required library as dependencies
from project structure -> dependencies -> app -> + -> `commonlib` and `mobilertc`

These are the dependencies in my `build.gradle` (:app)

```
dependencies { 

implementation fileTree(dir: “libs”, include: ["*.jar"]) 
implementation ‘androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0’ 
implementation ‘androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3’ 
implementation project(path: ‘:mobilertc’) 
implementation project(path: ‘:commonlib’) 
testImplementation ‘junit:junit:4.12’ 
androidTestImplementation ‘androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1’ 
androidTestImplementation ‘androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0’

}
```

Later in the documentation It says that

> Now you can import classes from the SDK in your own applications and
> enjoy the fantastic video conferencing experience in your apps.

I copied all the the package inside sdksample and pasted it in my zoomcustomintegration (package name of my app’s mainActivity is com.priyansh.zoomcustomintegration) but it say can’t resolve symbol us from any import that contains import us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK;

and tried

- sync project from gradle file
- invalidate and restart
- reload all from the disk

Error
While Running the app it says:
Error 1 as shown in image 1
Unable to resolve **us** in `import us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK` or sometimes it says unable to resolve **sdk** in `import us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK`
Error 2 as show in image 2
Build Error

> C:\Users\psult\Desktop\ZoomCustomInegrationV1\mobilertc\build.transforms\3bd9518bb58a8e93f142f05e10412654\jetified-mobilertc\AndroidManifest.xml

**Screenshots**

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Comment: How did you solve this? I am stuck here too @Priyansh

Answer (score 2):

You are importing `jars` from `libs` folder, but not `aars`.
Change:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: “libs”, include: ["*.jar"])
```

into:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: “libs”, include: ["*.aar"])
```

Comment: I imported .aars file but it automatically taking .jars in the dependencies. I explicitly checked it when you pointed it out.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Priyansh?

Comment: Yes, I successfully integrated ZoomSDK in my app.

Comment: What is the solution? I am stuck too.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way.**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    implementation files('libs/commonlib.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mobilertc.aar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
}
```